# Need advise with algorithm to get objects from List

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a List of objects:

```
class MyObj{
String name;
int value;
...
}
```

Objects in this list can be with equal names, but different values.

```
List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyObj("name1", 31));
list.add(new MyObj("name1", 442));
list.add(new MyObj("name2", 213));
list.add(new MyObj("name1", 31));
list.add(new MyObj("name2", 341));
list.add(new MyObj("name3", 131));
```

My goal is to make another List, without objects with the same names. And add values of all same objects into new ones.

Something like this: `new MyObj("name1", 31+442+31)` ...

I can't come up with right algorithm, how to get all "repeated" objects?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an algorithm attempt in the question... How much did you try to see when `obj1.name.equals(obj2.name)`?

Comment: Did your teacher by any chance introduce you to the `Map` class before giving you this task? How might that help?

Comment: Do you have to preserve the order of the items in the list?

Comment: @slim I don't have any teachers and why do i need Map? My object has much more than two fields

Comment: @BigCoach OK, so you have a String `name` and you need to find out whether you've seen it before. Consider how a `Map<String,MyObj>` could help you with that.

Comment: @JeremyP No, the order is not important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through your list with something like this Java-ish pseudocode:

```
 for(MyObj item : list) {
     String name = item.getName();
     if(haveSeen(name) {
         MyObj destinationItem = findDestinationItem(name);
         destinationItem.setValue(destinationItem.getValue() + item.getValue());
     } else {
         addDestinationItem(copy(item));
     }
 }
 return listDestinationItems();
```

The remaining question is how to implement `haveSeen(String name)`, `findDestinationItem(String name)`, `addDestinationItem(String name)` and `listDestinationItems()`.

You'll find that these map very nicely to `Map.contains()`, `Map.get()`, `Map.put()` and `Map.entrySet()`.  The OO way to do this is to work with a `Map` field, but you could also pass a `Map` to these methods e.g. `haveSeen(Map<String,MyObj> seenItems, String name)`.

Answer (score 4):

Collect your `MyObj`s into a map based on the name. If the name is the same combine the values:

```
Map<String,MyObj> map = list.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap((MyObj o) -> o.name, myObj -> myObj, (MyObj o1, MyObj o2) -> new MyObj(o1.name, o1.value + o2.value)));

map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
```

Prints

```
name3 MyObj [name=name3, value=131]
name2 MyObj [name=name2, value=554]
name1 MyObj [name=name1, value=504]
```

Then take the values from the map and convert it to a new List of `MyObj`

```
List<MyObj> newList = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

newList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
MyObj [name=name3, value=131]
MyObj [name=name2, value=554]
MyObj [name=name1, value=504]
```

You can combine these steps and not use the map in between. But I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a map for this:

```
map = new HashMap()
for el in list:
  if map.get(el.name) == null:
    map.put(el.name, el)
  else
    map.put(el.name, new El(el.name, el.value + map.get(el.name).value))
result = map.values()
```

The complexity of this algorithm `O(n*hashCodeOfString())`. It's basically `O(n)`

Comment: A nice simple understandable solution. I think you should add the declaration of `map` in though. e.g. `Map<String, MyObj>map = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 2):

Override `hashCode()` and use `HashSet<MyObj>` to merge same objects. Iterate the `hashSet` and put them into a new list.

```
  class MyObj {
    private String name;
    private int value;
    // other fields
    // ....

    // getter and setter

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return this.getName().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if(other == null) {
        return false;
      }
      if(!(other instanceof MyObj)) {
        return false;
      }
      if(this == (MyObj) other) {
        return true;
      }
      return this.getName().equals(((MyObj)other).getName());
    }
  }
```

This is a hint, not a complete answer. I would suggest to figure out the solution based on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the second list in a extra class.
Then you can write an add function which searches through the list if an object with the same name is already in there.
If so add the new value to the current value, if not add a new item to the list.

```
public class ListHandler {
    private List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListHandler instance = null;
    public ListHandler getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ListHandler();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addToList(MyObj objectToAdd) {
        for (MyObj obj : list) {
            if (obj.getName().equals(objectToAdd.getName())) {
                obj.addToValue(objectToAdd.getValue());
                return;
            }
        }
        list.add(objectToAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a task for streams:

```
Map<String, MyObj> result = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        MyObj::getName,
        Function.identity(),
        (a, b) -> new MyObj(a.getName(), a.getValue() + b.getValue())));
```

Here I'm using the [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) utility, which collects the elements of the stream by determining the key and value of the map, accepting a merge function that is used to merge elements when the key is equal.

If your `MyObj` class had this method:

```
public MyObj merge(MyObj another) {
    return new MyObj(this.getName(), this.getValue() + another.getValue());
}
```

You could simpify the collecting code above as follows:

```
Map<String, MyObj> result = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        MyObj::getName,
        Function.identity(),
        MyObj::merge));
```

Finally, you already have the `MyObj` collection in the values of the map:

```
Collection<MyObj> myObjects = results.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java8 (assumes that a getter `getName` is present in `MyObj`):

```
list.stream()
        //map names to sum of values associated with them
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObj::getName, Collectors.reducing(0, MyObj::getValue, Integer::sum))).entrySet()
        //transform map to stream of MyObj
    .stream().map(e->new MyObj(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        //collect into list
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `hashCode` and `equals` to your `MyObj` class you can have the distinct list in this way:

```
Map<MyObj, MyObj> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                obj -> obj, 
                (a, b) -> new MyObj(a.name, b.value + a.value)));
map.values()
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This returns:

```
MyObj [name=name3, value=131]
MyObj [name=name2, value=554]
MyObj [name=name1, value=504]
```

Comment: This doesn't add up the values of the parameters in MyObj